# How to extract the probability density function from SmoothHistogram?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, histograms

I have some data.I plot the histogram with `SmoothHistogram` in *Mathematica*. If the y-axis of the histogram is my p(x) function, I want to plot f(x)=(1/n)ln(p(x)) with *Mathematica*. I don't know how?!

```
data = Import["Desktop/kmc final result.txt", "List"];
d = SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"];
time = 200;

f[x_] := -1/time Log[d, x]
```

Comment: Welcome! Please add working code to demonstrate your problem. As it is, we cannot sensibly answer because of lack of information.

Comment: Data = Import["Desktop/kmc final result.txt", "List"];
d = SmoothHistogram[Data, Automatic, "PDF"];
time = 200;
f[x_] := -1/time Log[d, x];

Answer (score 5):

With some data

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000]
```

the `SmoothHistogram` plot:

```
SmoothHistogram[data]
```

> [image: SmoothHistogramPlot]

is using [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html).
You can create the same `DataDistribution` object using

```
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data]
```

and then extract the values you see in the plot at a specific single point e.g.

```
PDF[dist, 0.5]
```

> `0.347436`

create a table of values, e.g.:

```
Table[{x, PDF[dist, x]}, {x, -3.5, 3.5, 0.1}]
```

or use it within `Plot` or any other suitable function:

```
time = 200;
f[x_] := -1/time Log[PDF[dist, x]]
Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}]
```

> [image: Plot2]

Comment: So you mean that there is no difference between "smoothkerneldistribution" and "SmoothHistogram"?!

Comment: That is how I read the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram.html?q=SmoothHistogram): "SmoothHistogram[data] by default plots the PDF of [data], based on a smooth kernel density estimate. ... The specifications for bandwidth bw and kernel are the same as for SmoothKernelDistribution"

Comment: Thanx alot dear friend!

Answer (score 2):

As a an alternative, you can also extract the data out of the SmoothHistogram object. This way is a bit dirty and should be done carefully because the "magic index" 1,2,1,3,3,1 could be dependent on Mathematica version and other parameters.
This is for v10:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000];
dataHist = SmoothHistogram[data]
```

[image]

now directly access the list of plotted points by dataHist[[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]]

```
dataHist[[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]] // ListLinePlot
{#[[1]], 1/1000*Log[#[[2]]]} & /@dataHist[[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]] // ListLinePlot
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: one small issue to be aware of , the plot range of `SmoothHistogram` seems to cut off the very ends of the tails.